# Bash sed deleting lines with words existing in another pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've got console output, sth like:

```
SECTION/foo
SECTION/fo1
SECTION/fo3

Foo = N
Fo1 = N
Fo2 = N
Fo3 = N
Bar = Y
```

as an output, I want to have:

```
Foo = N
Fo1 = N
Fo3 = N
```

Any (simple) solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts. [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: What makes those three lines special? I don't see the pattern

Comment: @joelgoldstick Foo, Fo1, and Fo3 are in first 3 lines, after SECTION/

Comment: They aren't. There's fo*2*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk -F' *[/=] *' '$1 == "SECTION" {a[tolower($2)]} tolower($1) in a' file

Foo = N
Fo1 = N
Fo3 = N
```

**Description:**

- We split each line using custom field separator as `' *[/=] *'` which means `/` or `=` surrounded with 0 or more spaces on each side.
- When first field is `SECTION` then we store each lowercase column 2 into an array `a`
- Later when lowercase first column is found in array `a` then we print each line (default action).

Comment: would you mind describing how it's working? Im not really familiar with awk, but It seems powerful :)

Comment: I've added some explanation in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne ' $h{ ucfirst $1 } = 1 if m(SECTION/(.*));
           print if /(.*) = / && $h{$1};
         ' < input
```

A hash table is created from lines containing `SECTION/`. If the line contains `=` and its left hand side is stored in the hash, it gets printed.

Comment: pluse-uno for "to the rescue" (and working code AND an explanation). Now where have I heard that expression before?! ;-) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/SECTION/H;s/.*/&\n&/;G;s/\n.*/\L&/;/\n(.*) .*\n.*\/\1/P' file
```

Collect all `SECTION` lines in the hold space (HS). Double the line and delimit by a newline. Append the collected lines from the HS and convert everything from the first newline to the end to lowercase. Using a backreference match the variable to the section suffix and if so print only the first line i.e. the original line unadulterated.

N.B. the `-n` invokes the grep-like nature of sed and the `-r` reduces the number of backslashes needed to write a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1 ~ /Foo|Fo1|Fo3/'  file 
Foo = N
Fo1 = N
Fo3 = N
```